# scrolling JLabel in Java

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jlabel, springlayout

i have a little issue with jlabel. When the label displays doubles which are to large for the screen, I would like to have a scrollbar to see them anyway. I have just added a scrollbar to the whole panel, but it does not check, when a overlong double is displayed.

here is my code

```
 public class OverviewPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JLabel textNoNodes = new JLabel();
    private JLabel textNoEdges = new JLabel();
    private JLabel textInitial = new JLabel();
    private JLabel textTargets = new JLabel();
    private JLabel textFilename = new JLabel();
    private JLabel textProbabilityModelCheck = new JLabel();
    private JLabel textProbabilityCounterExample = new JLabel();
    private JLabel textNoSteps = new JLabel();

    public OverviewPanel() {
        super(new SpringLayout());
        addRow("Number states", textNoNodes);
        addRow("Number edges", textNoEdges);
        addRow("Initial", textInitial);
        addRow("Targets", textTargets);
        addRow("Filename", textFilename);
        addRow("Prob. model check", textProbabilityModelCheck);
        addRow("Prob. counter example", textProbabilityCounterExample);
        addRow("Number steps", textNoSteps);
        SpringUtilities.makeCompactGrid(this, 8, 2, // rows, cols
                6, 6, // initX, initY
                6, 6); // xPad, yPad
        setDefault();
    }

    private void addRow(String text, JComponent component) {
        JLabel l = new JLabel(text);
        add(l);
        l.setLabelFor(component);       
        add(component);
    }
   ...
   }
```

Comment: are you re_create OverviewPanel on Runtime or OverviewPanel is created once times and you want to resize JComponets depends of its contents, converting lenght of text to the pixels

Comment: It is initially created with default values and reloads when an action did happen, but not like a listener. the reload function is explicitly called.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`pack()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack%28%29), which "Causes this `Window` to be sized to fit the preferred size and layouts of its subcomponents." An [sscce](http://sscce.org/) may be helpful, too.

Addendum: An instance of [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) may be help control extreme size variability.

Comment: I do not see how pack() is applicable to the outPutPanel. In fact it works with frames, but this is a JPanel.

Comment: Yes, you should invoke `pack()` on the panel's enclosing `Window`. Dynamically, you can use `revalidate()`, typically followed by `repaint()`.

Comment: Moreover, pack() will de-maximize a window... better use revalidate()+repaint()

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, I would use a modified `JTextArea` (i.e. disabled, wrapped, and opaque). **No scrolling, resizing, or font metric calculations required**!

Comment: +1 Along the same lines, a one-column `JTable` gives a nice result with type `Double`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, because I don't know springlayout, anyway I think you have to set the size of the label to the size of the text. To get it you can use:

```
FontMetrics fm = someComponent.getFontMetrics(someFont);
  int width = fm.stringWidth(someString);
```

maybe adding some extra space. Then with the label at the actual width the container *should* scroll...

Of course I'm talking of minimumSize or it is ineffective...

Comment: This seems needlessly laborious; the `JLabel` itself can calculate its own preferred size on validation.